# Woocommerce update price via update_post_meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I write a code that updates woocommerce prices via update_post_meta function.

The prices change at the mysql but there are not changes on the site.
I found that the price will update only if I'll change one of the variation to outofstock and then back to instock and save. (only to click on save variation).

Can someone help me? why the price doesn't update from the database?

Here is the update code

```
update_post_meta($id, '_price', $sale_price);

update_post_meta($id, '_sale_price', $sale_price);

update_post_meta($id, '_regular_price', $regular_price);

$id= post_id of variation and parent (loop)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Variable products are "synced" and if you've modified the variation prices outside of the admin then you've skipped the save action which re-syncs the prices for the parent product. Assuming you have a product object for a variable product you'd run `$product->variable_product_sync()`

Comment: Thanks, I added this code:
$product = wc_get_product( $id );
$product->variable_product_sync();
But now I got Server error (500)
Maybe I need some include?
Thanks!

Comment: This is only a fragment of your code, and you've not explained where/when you are running this so we don't have enough information to help you. Please edit your question to include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or in the WordPress sense the minimal function and what action hook it is running on.